# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} ⟨k_n, m_n⟩ = ⟨c, d⟩$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

Let ${k_n}$ and ${m_n}$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} k_n = c$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} m_n = d$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} ⟨k_n, m_n⟩ = ⟨c, d⟩$.

My thinking:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} k_n m_n = cd$$
$$|k_nm_n-cd|<\epsilon$$
$$||k_nm_n||-||cd||\leq|k_nm_n-cd|<\epsilon$$

then ?
edit. $⟨k_n, m_n⟩ = ⟨c, d⟩$ are inner product.

Comment: What do $k_n,m_n$ and $\langle c,d\rangle$ mean?

Comment: Please correct the statement $\lim_{n \to \infty} k_n , m_n = \langle c,d\rangle$. Do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty}\langle k_n,m_n\rangle = \langle c,d\rangle$ where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ indicates the usual dot/inner product on $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes!. edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\left( \mathbf{a_n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\left( \mathbf{b_n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are sequences in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$ \mathbf{a}_n, \mathbf{b}_n \in \mathbf{R}^k, $$
and thus
$$ \mathbf{a_n} = \left( \alpha_{n1}, \ldots, \alpha_{nk} \right) $$
and
$$ \mathbf{b_n} = \left( \beta_{n1}, \ldots, \beta_{nk} \right), $$
where
$$ \alpha_{ni}, \beta_{ni} \in \mathbb{R} $$
for  $i = 1, \ldots, k$.

Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$ \left\langle \mathbf{a}_n, \mathbf{b}_n \right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_{nk}\beta_{nk}. $$

Now let
$$  \mathbf{a} = \left( \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k \right) $$
and
$$  \mathbf{b} = \left( \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_k \right) $$
be any elements of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Then 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{a}_n = \mathbf{a} $$
if and only if
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_{ni} = \alpha_i $$
for each $i = 1, \ldots, k$.

And, similarly, 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{b}_n = \mathbf{b} $$
if and only if
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta_{ni} = \beta_i $$
for each $i = 1, \ldots, k$.

Therefore if 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{a}_n = \mathbf{a} \ \mbox{ and } \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{b}_n = \mathbf{b}, $$
then we have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_{ni} = \alpha_i \ \mbox{ and } \  \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta_{ni} = \beta_i $$
for each $i = 1, \ldots, k$.

Hence we have 
$$
\begin{align}
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\langle \mathbf{a}_n, \mathbf{b}_n \right\rangle &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_{ni}\beta_{ni} \right) \\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^k \left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \alpha_{ni} \beta_{ni} \right) \right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \left[  \left( \lim_{n \to \infty}  \alpha_{ni} \right) \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta_{ni} \right) \right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \beta_i \\
&= \langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle.
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps.

Should have any confusion, or further questions, please feel free to inquire.

Comment: I've always loved your questions and answers,+1.

Comment: Saaqib. Very nice.

Comment: @Saaqib Mahmood, Hi, for the last part, where you move the limit into the summation, isn't this restricted to uniformly convergent sequences? If so, how can i show that with the limit?

Comment: @MathAvengers since your $k$ is a fixed natural number, all we have done is use a generalisation of the fact that $$ \lim \left(x_n+y_n \right) = \lim x_n + \lim y_n. $$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I mean the step before that, where you have the summation out :)

Comment: @MathAvengers please have a look at my proof again. I've made some corrections.